# Unzip too slow for transfer of many files

Tags: windows, zip, 7zip

We need to distribute lots of small jpg files to offline systems. Right now, we send it as a 7zip  (or plain zip) which is 800MB (230K files) and use 7zip to unzip it. It is taking about an hour to unzip on fairly large 4 core processors.

Is there a way on windows7 (or win server 2008) to create and unpack a package of files of this size in a more reasonable time frame?

(I will entertain even far out answers such as: put this all in a single CloudDB database as binary blobs and then ship the archive to the target machine, or create a VM, or a virtual disk image - but I will need some pointers to tips on doing that sort of stuff).

Comment: One more point, I am expanding the zip to a virtual folder of an APACHE web server (that is where all the JPG's are going) so if there was an extension for APACHE that lets it mount a ZIP structure for a virtual folder, that would probably also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So then here's your far out answer: ;)

The problem probably doesn't lie in computing power. The filesystem and/or harddisk are the bottleneck most likely.

For Win7 (and afaik Server2008 as well) you could [use a Virtual Hard Disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872416.aspx) instead of zipping it. Win7 has native support for VHD-files and can emulate the content as a drive or subfolder via Disk Management. So there would be no need to unzip the files.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I see win server 2008 has it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323684(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am going to try this, but on a different stack overflow thread I am giving more details of what we need to do, and what we have tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404878/robocopy-virtual-hard-disk-or-other

Comment: This is working great for us. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it. The issue is likely the Windows Attachment Service, which subjects downloaded or attached zip files to additional scrutiny for security reasons.

To bypass this:

1. Right-click the file
2. Choose Properties
3. Check Unblock

For more info, see: [Why is WinZip slow?](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/13/)

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to some colleagues, and they might have an easier solution. Since the size is under 4GB, and I want READ-ONLY access, I can create an ISO image, and then mount it on win7 or win2008server, using this Microsoft utility:

**[This utility enables users of Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7 to mount ISO disk image files as virtual CD-ROM drives.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38780)**

Comment: This ISO technique works, but is not going to fly with our customers, I stared a new thread that details more of what we are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404878/robocopy-virtual-hard-disk-or-other